# Can't access property when using a |

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

Here's my code:

```
type DetailsItemEditInput = {
  type: 'text' | 'number';
};

type DetailsItemEditDropdown = {
  type: 'dropdown';
  options: [];
};

type DetailsItemEdit = DetailsItemEditDropdown | DetailsItemEditInput;

export const DetailsItemEdit: FC<DetailsItemEdit> = ({ type, ...props }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'text' || 'number':
      return <Input type={type} />;
    case 'dropdown':
      return <Select options={props.options} />;
    default:
      return <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>Wrong type</div>;
  }
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

I want the options property to be required, only when the type is a 'dropdown'. I thought I might do this with a `|`. But unfortunately, `props` doesn't seem to have the options property in the `<Select .../>` part. What am I missing?

```
Property 'options' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; } | { options: []; children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'options' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is not smart enough to narrow the type of the `props` in your code. If you do not destructure the props the code should work.

Comment: Right on, thanks!. Is there no way to destructure them?

Comment: @alex Probably not, because it will hide the connection between `type` and `options`.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you!